# How to set global modules in multiple node.js files

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I have a project which i'm working on, but i realised it was over 2000 lines and wanted to split it up into different files for different group of functions. eg. send message and read message functions are in message.js. The problem is that i need alot of modules in each of the files and if i create an instance of the module, i will need to create a new instance in another file, but i want to use the same instance!

I've tried `module.exports = { ... }` and `exports.function()` to pass the modules and instances to other files but sometimes it says that the function does not exist.

For example in my app.js file:

```
const module = require('module')
instance = new module()

const message = require('./message.js')
message.passModule(instance)
```

And in my message.js file:

```
let module-instance

exports.passModule = function(instance) {
    module-instance = instance
}

module-instance.doSomething()
```

So, how could I have all the modules to be available in all the files, but only declare them in one, and how do I get the instance I made in one File to be able to be used in the other Files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some library file

*singleton/file.js*

```
const someDependency = require('some-module');

class Singleton {
  method() {
    ...
    return someDependency.someFunctionality();
  }
  ...
}
module.exports = new Singleton();
```

Someplace where you want to use your singleton

```
const singleton = require('singleton/file');
singleton.method();
```

Comment: Thanks, so I put the instances and modules in the class?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by modules (in js module means file with some code) but you don't need class purse but if you do for example this `module.exports = { method: () => {} }` that method still can be used as in above example. Just if you want singleton dont create new instances outside of the singleton module file. No `new module` outside of module that supposed to be singleton.

Comment: Module meant npm modules

Comment: ok whenever you do `require('some-module')` you need to do it only in places where you need to use some part of that module and it will always return same version. I will add it to example.

Comment: Updated answer does that answers your question?

Comment: Alright, i'll mess around with it and see if can fix it